# Why can't I see the methods of AppiumLibrary when I subclass it?

Tags: python, appium, robotframework, python-appium

In [this StackOverflow posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889387/robot-framework-passing-appium-driver-to-python-script) Bryan Oakley suggested subclassing AppiumLibrary and gave an example of doing so. I’m trying to do this and I can’t seem to get it to work. For example:

```
ActivePython 2.7.2.5 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 24 2011, 12:20:15)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type “help”, “copyright”, “credits” or “license” for more information.

>>> from AppiumLibrary import AppiumLibrary
>>> class foo(AppiumLibrary):
…     pass
…
>>> f = foo()
>>> print f
<__main__.foo object at 0x102097bd0>
>>> print f.__dict__

{‘_running_on_failure_routine’: False, ‘_screenshot_index’: 0, ‘_run_on_failure_keyword’: ‘Capture Page Screenshot’, ‘_element_finder’: <AppiumLibrary.locators.elementfinder.ElementFinder object at 0x1036f7e50>, ‘_timeout_in_secs’: 5.0, ‘_bi’: <robot.libraries.BuiltIn.BuiltIn object at 0x1036f7d50>, ‘_cache’: <AppiumLibrary.utils.applicationcache.ApplicationCache object at 0x1036f7d90>}

>>> f.OpenApplication()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “<stdin>”, line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: ‘foo’ object has no attribute ‘OpenApplication’
```

Why did this work for Bryan and AronS and not now for me?

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Boy do I feel stupid! As soon as I re-ready my own posting of the question I knew the answer. The Robot Framework keyword is "Open Application" but the internal keyword method in AppiumLibrary is "open_application". When subclassing you have to call by the actual method name, not by RobotFramework's "friendly" keyword name!

I'm still not clear why **dict** doesn't list the keyword method names, but maybe I'm being dumb about something in Python that I should also know without asking.

Comment: `__dict__` is for attributes. I think what you want to do is `dir(f)`. That will show all the methods and attributes. To try and see just public methods - `[x for x in dir(f) if inspect.ismethod(getattr(f,x)) and x[0]!='_']`. Of course there are exceptions to all this.