# Click radio button coupled to a label with same name using Firefox WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, radio-button

I'm using Selenium 3.12.0 with Python 3.7.2 and Firefox 66.0.1 on Fedora 29. I'm having trouble clicking a radio button. The radio button is inside a label, and the radio and label use the same name. The page is located at https://complaints.donotcall.gov/complaint/complaintcheck.aspx.

```
<label for="PrerecordMessageYESRadioButton">
    <input id="PrerecordMessageYESRadioButton" type="radio" name="PrerecMsg" value="PrerecordMessageYESRadioButton" tabindex="7">
    <label for="PrerecordMessageYESRadioButton">Yes</label>
</label>
```

When I examine a screenshot after the page has been completed, I see the radio buttons are not clicked. The other elements on the page are completed OK.

I've tried `driver.find_element_by_id("PrerecordMessageYESRadioButton")`, `driver.find_element_by_name("PrerecMsg")` and `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#PrerecordMessageYESRadioButton")`. Once selected, I've also tried `radio.click()`, `radio.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`,  and `radio.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)` with no joy. Finally, `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", radio)` was not helpful, either.

How does one click the radio button coupled to a label in this case?

---

Radio buttons seem to cause a fair amount of trouble. Here are some related questions, but they did not help in this instance of the problem. The first reference and @yong's answer seems very relevant to this problem.

- [Selenium find element_by_id not working with radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48746229/608639)
- [How to select radio button with Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30183424/608639)
- [Using Selenium in Python to click/select a radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21322116/608639)
- [Unable to click on a radio button in Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32307141/608639)

---

Here is the test script:

```
$ cat test-driver.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

def main():

    opts = Options()
    opts.headless = True
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts)   

    #################################################

    print("Fetching page 1")    
    driver.get("https://complaints.donotcall.gov/complaint/complaintcheck.aspx")

    print("Clicking Continue")
    button_continue = driver.find_element_by_id("ContinueButton")
    button_continue.click()

    #################################################

    print("Fetching page 2")    
    time.sleep(2) 

    text_phone = driver.find_element_by_id("PhoneTextBox")
    for ch in "8005551212":
        text_phone.send_keys(ch)

    text_calendar = driver.find_element_by_id("DateOfCallTextBox")
    for ch in "03/30/2019":
        text_calendar.send_keys(ch)

    dropdown_hour = driver.find_element_by_id("TimeOfCallDropDownList")
    dropdown_hour.send_keys("10")

    dropdown_minute = driver.find_element_by_id("ddlMinutes")
    dropdown_minute.send_keys("30")

    # PrerecordMessageYESRadioButton
    radio_robocall = driver.find_element_by_name("PrerecMsg")
    # radio_robocall = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#PrerecordMessageYESRadioButton")
    radio_robocall.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    radio_robocall.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
    ...

    driver.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

Enumerating the elements on the page by id:

```
ids = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id]')
for val in ids:
    print(val.get_attribute('id'))
```

Returns the following:

```
Head1
_fed_an_ua_tag
bdyComplaint
top
changeLang
topnav
navbtn
mobileChangeLang
Form1
__EVENTTARGET
__EVENTARGUMENT
__VIEWSTATE
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR
__EVENTVALIDATION
StepOnePanel
StepOneEntryPanel
ErrorMsg
PhoneTextBox
DateOfCallTextBox
TimeOfCallDropDownList
ddlMinutes
PrerecordMessageYESRadioButton
PrerecordMessageNORadioButton
PhoneCallRadioButton
MobileTextMessageRadioButton
ddlSubjectMatter
spnTxtSubjectMatter
txtSubjectMatter
StepOneContinueButton
hdnBlockBack
hdnPhoneChecked
hdnCompanyChecked
hdnPhoneNumber
```

---

Here is what I am seeing after fetching the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Tried your code, `driver.find_element_by_id("PrerecordMessageYESRadioButton").click()` worked fine for me (Selenium 3.141, Python 3.7.2).

Comment: I'm curios, why do you type the text char by char to the fields?

Comment: Thanks @Guy. I am working remotely over SSH. Could the remote headless screenshot be the problem? In this case, then there may not be a problem. I use character entry to simulate typing by a user.

Comment: Actually I doubt that. Do you have a way to check the "results" of the form? if the values has been updated in some DB or somewhere else? You can also try running it on regular (not headless) browser and see what happens.

Comment: Add `radio_robocall.click()` and `print(f"radio_robocall status: {str(radio_robocall.is_selected())}")`after `radio_robocall = driver.find_element_by_name("PrerecMsg")` to check if radio is selected

Comment: Thanks @Guy. I added the screenshot. It is interesting (in a morbid sort of way) it works for you but not me. I may be able to cross-check some of the results by inspecting the [data files the FTC publishes](https://www.ftc.gov/site-information/open-government/data-sets/do-not-call-data). However, the FTC publishes the new daily list on weekday mornings, so I usually have to wait one day.

Comment: @jww It seems the radio buttons are missing from the page (open the page locally to see the difference). Maybe it's an old FF version?

Comment: Thanks again @Guy. When I attach a monitor and login to the computer, I can open the page in Firefox and it renders as expected. At the same time, the problem persists when testing headless.

Comment: Thanks @Sers. `radio_robocall YES status: True`. I also checked `PrerecordMessageNORadioButton`, and it returned `radio_robocall NO status: False`. I'm guessing that means this is a headless GUI problem, and not a real problem.

Comment: @jww it's mean radio selected. Don't pay attention to screenshot. To be sure add `print(f"radio_robocall status: {str(radio_robocall.is_selected())}")` before click also, result should be `False`

Comment: Thanks again @Sers. Adding `radio_robocall.is_selected()` before the click returned `radio_robocall YES status: False`. I think it is a bug in the testing gear.

Comment: @Guy - The FTC just published their daily list. The number I added using Selenium was present in the list. So it looks the radio button is checked even though the screenshot does not show it. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check radio status using `is_selected`:

```
radio_robocall = driver.find_element_by_name("PrerecMsg")
# is_selected should return False
print(f"radio_robocall status: {str(radio_robocall.is_selected())}")

radio_robocall.click()
# is_selected should return True
print(f"radio_robocall status: {str(radio_robocall.is_selected())}")
```

Comment: Thanks, `radio_robocall.is_selected` worked as expected. I was struggling with this issue for two days. Sigh...

Comment: One more issue if you can lend your expertise: [Selenium chromedriver exception when enumerating elements by xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55763358/608639).