# Python and Selenium To “execute_script” to solve “ElementNotVisibleException”

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, execute-script

I am using Selenium to save a webpage. The content of webpage will change once certain checkbox(s) are clicked. What I want is to click a checkbox then save the page content. (The checkboxes are controlled by JavaScript.)

Firstly I used:

```
driver.find_element_by_name("keywords_here").click()
```

it ends with an error:

```
NoSuchElementException
```

then I tried “xpath” like, with implicit/explicit waiting:

```
URL = “the url”

verificationErrors = []
accept_next_alert = True

aaa = driver.get(URL)
driver.maximize_window()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

#driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[contains(text(), ' keywords_here')]").click()
#Or: 

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),' keywords_here')]/../input[@type='checkbox']").click()
```

it gives an error:

```
ElementNotVisibleException
```

Posts

[How to force Selenium WebDriver to click on element which is not currently visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101461/how-to-force-selenium-to-click-on-element-which-is-not-currently-visible#)

[Selenium Element not visible exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27927964/selenium-element-not-visible-exception)

suggest it should make the checkboxes visible before clicking, for example using:

```
execute_script
```

The question may sounds stupid, but how can I find out the proper sentence to “execute_script” the visibility of checkbox from the page source code?

Besides that, is there another way?

Thanks.

by the way, the line html code looks like:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="ComponentArt_HandleCheck(this,'p3',11);" name="keywords_here">
```

its xpath looks like:

```
//*[@id="TreeView1_item_11"]/tbody/tr/td[3]/input
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Alternative option would be to make the `click()` inside `execute_script()`:

```
# wait for element to become present
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
checkbox = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "keywords_here")))

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", checkbox)
```

where `EC` is imported as:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

---

Alternatively and as an another shot in the dark, you can use the `element_to_be_clickable` Expected Condition and perform the click in a usual way:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
checkbox = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "keywords_here")))

checkbox.click()
```

Comment: Sir alecxe, thanks for the help. You are an expert. I’ve read some of you posts. I tried the lines but both of them give “raise TimeoutException(message)” “selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: ''.

Comment: @MarkK thank you. But, at the same time `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),' keywords_here')]/../input[@type='checkbox']")` does not produce an error? Have you checked that the xpath you use inside the  `find_element_by_xpath` is the same used inside the "Expected Conditions" I've posted? Thanks.

Comment: (sorry there's a mistake - I replaced you posted to what I had but actually I think your lines are to be added after the original lines. ) I added your lines into the originals and the xpaths in them are the same. the     driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),' keywords_here')]/../input[@type='checkbox']") itself gives "NoSuchElementException".

Comment: @MarkK okay, thanks. Then this means we have a different problem. We are not locating the element correctly. I've updated the answer and used the `By.NAME` location technique. Check if we still get the  `NoSuchElementException`. Thanks.

Comment: thanks again. Does it mean only using the EC lines, or xpath lines together? (and if both EC and xpath, which goes first?) I tried only the EC By.NAME, it gives "selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: ". by the way, there's keyword "iframe" in the webpage's source code. is (the checkbox is in the iframe) it a concern? thanks.

Comment: @MarkK oh yeah, that's a game changer. You need to switch to an iframe before looking for that checkbox element. For instance: `driver.switch_to.frame("frame_id_or_name")`.

Comment: sir alecxe. thanks again for your replies. the problem is solved finally by using the whole xpath for its find_element_by_xpath. much appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

I had some issues with expected conditions, I prefer building my own timeout.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import \
    NoSuchElementException, \
    WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

b = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'the url'
b.get(url)
locator_type = By.XPATH
locator = "//label[contains(text(),' keywords_here')]/../input[@type='checkbox']"
timeout = 10
success = False
wait_until = time.time() + timeout
while wait_until < time.time():
    try:
        element = b.find_element(locator_type, locator)
        assert element.is_displayed()
        assert element.is_enabled()
        element.click() # or if you really want to use an execute script for it, you can do that here.
        success = True
        break
    except (NoSuchElementException, AssertionError, WebDriverException):
        pass
if not success:
    error_message = 'Failed to click the thing!'
    print(error_message)
```

might want to add InvalidElementStateException, and StaleElementReferenceException