# Python Selenium input check click failed

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, input, checkbox, selenium-chromedriver

I have following html:

```
<input id="!T1319457706_SPY" type="checkbox" name="!T1319457706_SPY" class="checkbox" onclick="toggleTextField(['1319457706'],this.checked,'','');" style="">
```

This is checkbox that I want to click,I have tried all the selector to locate it,but all failed and system have no error message,in this page I have tried to click other element,it works,expect this checkbox.

I have tried follow ways:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('!T1319457706_SPY').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='!T1319457706_SPY']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body[@class='grdtradeOrder']//form[@name='displayopenorders']//table[@class='t0']//tr[@name='orderid1319457706']//input[@name='!T1319457706_SPY']").click()
```

I also tried use:

```
 click_check=driver.find_element_by_id('!T1319457706_SPY')

 driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", click_check)
```

All above tries have failed.Any friend can help?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that clicking the checkbox calls a javascript code as seen from the `onClick` expression in the HTML code.

You could directly execute that javascript code using the `execute_script` function

`driver.execute_script(""toggleTextField(['1319457706'],this.checked,'','');")`

Or maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31397512/9809865) could help you. This clicks on the checkbox using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
click_check = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[onclick*='toggleTextField']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", click_check)
```