# Unable to click on radio button Internet explorer

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to get the radio button clicked using Selenium web driver in IE browser.

The html is as follows:

```
<TD class=PlainText>
<INPUT onclick="javascript: ShowHideInvoicePanel();setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$cphClaimFlow$tabcontainerClaimFlow$tabFulfillment$Shipping$rdoYesFindMyPhone\',\'\')', 0)" id=ctl00_cphClaimFlow_tabcontainerClaimFlow_tabFulfillment_Shipping_rdoYesFindMyPhone type=radio value=rdoYesFindMyPhone name=ctl00$cphClaimFlow$tabcontainerClaimFlow$tabFulfillment$Shipping$phoneanswer>
<LABEL for=ctl00_cphClaimFlow_tabcontainerClaimFlow_tabFulfillment_Shipping_rdoYesFindMyPhone>Yes</LABEL>
<INPUT onclick="javascript: ShowHideInvoicePanel();setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$cphClaimFlow$tabcontainerClaimFlow$tabFulfillment$Shipping$rdoNoFindMyPhone\',\'\')', 0)" id=ctl00_cphClaimFlow_tabcontainerClaimFlow_tabFulfillment_Shipping_rdoNoFindMyPhone type=radio value=rdoNoFindMyPhone name=ctl00$cphClaimFlow$tabcontainerClaimFlow$tabFulfillment$Shipping$phoneanswer>
<LABEL for=ctl00_cphClaimFlow_tabcontainerClaimFlow_tabFulfillment_Shipping_rdoNoFindMyPhone>No</LABEL>
```

Below is my code:

```
WebDriverWait waitForErasePhnYesRadio=new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOut);
    WebElement elementErasePhnYesRadio= waitForErasePhnYesRadio.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("ctl00_cphClaimFlow_tabcontainerClaimFlow_tabFulfillment_Shipping_rdoYesFindMyPhone")));
    elementErasePhnYesRadio.click();
    logger.info("Clicked on Yes button of erase phone script");

    if(elementErasePhnYesRadio.isSelected()==false){
        System.out.println("is radio btn selected 1 : "+elementErasePhnYesRadio.isSelected());
        elementErasePhnYesRadio.click();
        System.out.println("is radio btn selected 2 : "+elementErasePhnYesRadio.isSelected());
    }
    System.out.println("is radio btn selected 3 : "+elementErasePhnYesRadio.isSelected());
```

I have added wait statement as I am waiting fro radio button to be displayed. The code is executing and no error or exception is displayed.

Below output is printed in console:

```
INFO [main] (ShippingPage.java:45) - Clicked on Yes button of erase phone script
is radio btn selected 1 : false
is radio btn selected 2 : false
is radio btn selected 3 : false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see Ids enclosed in quotes.....please check that too.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
Js.executeScript("document.getElementById('ctl00_cphClaimFlow_tabcontainerClaimFlow_tabFulfillment_Shipping_rdoYesFindMyPhone').checked = true;");
```

try the above code using JS executor and [See this link](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#native-events-and-internet-explorer) the  selenium doc says, mouse should not hover while script execution, since in IE it is completely depend on native events.

Finally sometimes [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37114800/weird-python-selenium-button-click-behaviour/37115451#37115451) may happen.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_cphClaimFlow_tabcontainerClaimFlow_tabFulfillment_Shipping_rdoYesFindMyPhone")).click();
```

Comment: This code searching for element with the given id and clicks on it