# Logging into website using selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium, autologin

I am trying to use selenium to log into this website: 
but it says the password and login are not visible. I looked around and saw that some people said to wait, but waiting does not seem to help. Here is my code:

```
    # importing libraries
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import re, time, csv


driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://platform.openquake.org/account/login/")
driver.switch_to
driver.maximize_window
time.sleep(10)

username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
username.send_keys("hi there")
```

Error message is :

```
ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27927964/selenium-element-not-visible-exception

Comment: Hmm its a bit confusing on how to do it for my particular circumstance. I was able to solve use tab to get around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPATH actually matches two elements. The non-plural driver methods (`find_element_by_XXX`) return the first element they find a match for, which in this case is not the one you want.

A good debugging tool for situations like this is to use the plural forms (`find_elements_by_XXX`) and then see how many elements matched.

In this case, you should do what Tanu suggested and use a more restrictive XPATH:

```
username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='controls']/input[@id='id_username']")
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='controls']/input[@id='id_password']")
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll make sure to use this!

Answer (score 1):

Modify your xpath:

```
username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='controls']/input[@id='id_username']")
```