# Submitting a Form using Selenium in Python

Tags: javascript, python, forms, selenium

I need to scrape some data behind those hyperlinks from [this Site](http://www.echemportal.org/echemportal/propertysearch/treeselect_input.action?queryID=PROQ3h3n). However, those hyperlinks are `javascript function calls`, which later submits a `form` using `post` method. After some search, `selenium` seems to be a candidate. So my question is that how should I properly set a value to an input tag and submit the form which does not a submit a button.

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "http://www.echemportal.org/echemportal/propertysearch/treeselect_input.action?queryID=PROQ3h3n"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
treePath_tag = driver.find_element_by_name("treePath")
```

Before submitting the form, I need to assign value to tag `<input>`. However, I got an error

> Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted
>   with

```
treePath_tag.send_keys('/TR.SE00.00/QU.SE.DATA_ENV/QU.SE.ENV_ENVIRONMENT_DATA/QU.SE.EN_MONITORING')
```

IF above is correct, I would like to submit form this way. Is it correct?

```
selenium.find_element_by_name("add_form").submit()
```

Below are sources from the web page.

#### JavaScript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AddBlock(path){
        document.add_form.treePath.value=path;
        document.add_form.submit();
    }
</script>
```

#### form "add_form"

```
<form id="addblock_input" name="add_form" action="/echemportal/propertysearch/addblock_input.action" method="post" style="display:none;">
<table class="wwFormTable" style="display:none;"><tr style="display:none;">
  <td colspan="2">
<input type="hidden" name="queryID" value="PROQ3h1w" id="addblock_input_queryID"/>  </td>
</tr>
<tr style="display:none;">
  <td colspan="2">
<input type="hidden" name="treePath" value="" id="addblock_input_treePath"/>  </td>
</tr>
</table></form>
```

#### div with javascript call

```
<div id="querytree">
    <h1>Property Search</h1>
    <h2>Select Query Block Type</h2>
    <p>Select a section for which to define query criteria.</p>
    <div class="queryblocktools"><a href="javascript:document.load_form.submit();"><img style="vertical-align:top;" alt="Load" src="/echemportal/etc/img/load.gif"/>&nbsp;Load Query</a></div>
    <ul class="listexpander">   
    <li>Physical and chemical properties<ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:AddBlock('/TR.SE00.00/QU.SE.DATA_PHYS/QU.SE.PC_MELTING');">Melting point/freezing point</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:AddBlock('/TR.SE00.00/QU.SE.DATA_PHYS/QU.SE.PC_BOILING');">Boiling point</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27927964/selenium-element-not-visible-exception/27931726#27931726) with `execute_script`?

Comment: Y should you want to assign value to a hidden field? <input type = "hidden"/> won't display in the browser GUI

Comment: @Aishu thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to set value on `hidden` input is which not visible on the page, that's why error has occurred. If you want to set value on `hidden` field try using `execute_script` as below :-

```
treePath_tag = driver.find_element_by_name("treePath")
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].value = arguments[1]', treePath_tag, '/TR.SE00.00/QU.SE.DATA_ENV/QU.SE.ENV_ENVIRONMENT_DATA/QU.SE.EN_MONITORING')
```

After setting value on `hidden` field you can use following to `submit` the form :-

```
selenium.find_element_by_name("add_form").submit()
```

Hope it helps..:)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! What is the meaning of `arguments[0].value=argument[1]' since I got this error `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: arguements is not defined`

Comment: @tao.hong sorry its `arguments[1]`..just typo mistake..here arguments[0] is your hidden element and arguments[1] is your value which you want to set...:)

Comment: No worries. But I still think it requires to define `arguments` since I got this msg `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: arguements is not defined`

Comment: Thanks again. But this time, it looks the program was halted... It opened firefox then my python console did not get any return/response...

Comment: @tao.hong Is there any exception?? WHAT you expecte in return?? could you explain more??

Comment: Sure. There is no exception, which is quite strange. I would like to fill that hidden input tag and submit the form, which will go to a different page to fill another form and scrap some data. Thanks again!

Comment: SO how did you know the code didn't fill the data in hidden field while its not visible??

Comment: Here is how I plan to check. `driver.execute_script('arguments[1].value = arguments[1]', treePath_tag, '/TR.SE00.00/QU.SE.DATA_ENV/QU.SE.ENV_ENVIRONMENT_DATA/QU.SE.EN_MONITORING')
treePath_tag2 = driver.find_element_by_name("treePath")
print treePath_tag2.get_attribute('value')`

Comment: @tao.hong Your are executing wrong script try as :-  `driver.execute_script('arguments[0].value = arguments[1]', treePath_tag, '/TR.SE00.00/QU.SE.DATA_ENV/QU.SE.ENV_ENVIRONMENT_DATA/QU.SE.EN_MONITORING')`... here first is `arguments[0]` and another is `arguments[1]`..then get and print..

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Any reference for those `arguments`? just try to understand this better. thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Ok I'm trying make it clear...in selenium `execute_script()` method expect two parameters where first is JavaScript expression as string and another is array of string...here in the second parameter which array of string is used as input for the java script expression...in JavaScript expression it suppose array of string input  in `arguments` variable, means array..as you see in your case in execute_script three param passed where first is JavaScript expression and other two is arguments array where arguments[0] is your hidden element and another arguments[1] is your value..

Comment: Thanks so much for explaining this process!

Comment: @tao.hong Have a look for more details..https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html..