# Scraping a form using python, BeautifulSoup when form uses primefaces

Tags: python, primefaces, beautifulsoup

As many others have asked, I am trying to use BeautifulSoup in python script to submit data to this [form](https://www.sos.state.co.us/voter/pages/pub/olvr/findVoterReg.xhtml), and retrieve the results.

I have tried to follow this [example](http://jonathansoma.com/lede/foundations-2017/classes/adv-scraping/advanced-scraping-form-submission/), which closely matches my need, particularly the section 'Sending data with the form request'. The example neatly packages the form input parameters in an array that is then passed in a POST request.

But when using Chrome's developer tools to see the network responses to this form, I cannot seem to find the query string, because it is wrapped up in the primefaces javascript used on the page.

Can anyone point out where this might be, and how to formulate this in python?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38520970/submitting-a-form-using-selenium-in-python#38521635