# Selenium - ElementNotVisibleException

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests

I saw plenty of questions / answer on this ElementNotVisibleException issue with selenium.
The best code I have done so far is the following :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium                      import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by  import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support    import expected_conditions as EC
url      = "http://www.cfnews.net/user/login"
driver.get(url)
print "Got url."
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
login_form = wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "user-login")), "pbm")
print "Element located."
displayed = login_form.is_displayed()
print "login_form.is_displayed() = ", displayed
login_form.send_keys("a")
```

which give the following output :

```
Got url.
Element located.
login_form.is_displayed() =  False
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ElementNotVisibleException                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-110-d45e06b37320> in <module>()
     12 displayed = login_form.is_displayed()
     13 print "login_form.is_displayed() = ", displayed
---> 14 login_form.send_keys("a")

/Users/romain/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.pyc in send_keys(self, *value)
    345                 value = self._upload(local_file)
    346 
--> 347         self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
    348 
    349     # RenderedWebElement Items

/Users/romain/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.pyc in _execute(self, command, params)
    492             params = {}
    493         params['id'] = self._id
--> 494         return self._parent.execute(command, params)
    495 
    496     def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

/Users/romain/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.pyc in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    234         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    235         if response:
--> 236             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    237             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    238                 response.get('value', None))

/Users/romain/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.pyc in check_response(self, response)
    190         elif exception_class == UnexpectedAlertPresentException and 'alert' in value:
    191             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, value['alert'].get('text'))
--> 192         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    193 
    194     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426935 (820a95b0b81d33e42712f9198c215f703412e1a1),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.0 x86_64)
```

So, the page is downloaded, the html is got by the driver, but it is not possible to send any key.
There is also the answer here : 
[Selenium Element not visible exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27927964/selenium-element-not-visible-exception)

Which proposes to use ActionChain, but I tried without success :(

If I do :

```
driver.page_source
```

I got the html :

```
u'<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"><head>\n        \n                                                                                    \n<title>Ouverture de session / Utilisateur - l\'actualit\xe9 du capital investissement : transactions LBO, M&amp;A, Venture France - Corporate Finance et Private Equity</title>\n<meta name="description" content="CFNEWS est le premier site \xe0 proposer actualit\xe9s et r\xe9f\xe9rentiels du corporate finance en France sur les...etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this and sucess!!!

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium                      import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by  import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support    import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url      = "http://www.cfnews.net/user/login"
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
login_form = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#nom-user")))

login_form.send_keys("a")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ".invisibility_of_element_located" you can  try "visibility_of_element_located".