# cannot login with selenium

Tags: selenium, automation

I am trying to automate logging into this [website](http://vatgia.com).

the login menu is at the top right of the website.

i have tried to find the login form by CSS selector, Xpath, name and the action of this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27927964/selenium-element-not-visible-exception).

edit 1 : I have also tried hover the mouse over the login with actionchains then find by elements. No Element was found, no key was sent also.

**Result:**

the find by `CSS`, `Xpath`, name shows : element not visible ;
the action event : i hover the mouse over the login area, send keys,the login area pops up but no key was sent, no error shown.

**My code for the action event:**

```
wd.get("http://www.vatgia.com")

action = ActionChains(wd);

action.move_to_element(wd.find_element_by_css_selector("#header_bar > div > div.fr > a:nth-child(8)"))
action.send_keys("loginsampling")

action.perform();
```

p/s : thankyou Brian for the edit !

**Final update :**

Mahipal has provided me with the solution. i should have used the xpath with regards to the container for the login form and password. i previously only right click and copy the xpath element and that did not work. Thanks Mahipal !

Comment: You are welcome, Kien :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the container of login menu for identifying its fields, as shown below:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='header_bar']//a[@rel='#header_login']")).click();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='simple_tip']//div/input[@name='loginname']"))));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='simple_tip']//div/input[@name='loginname']")).sendKeys("login_name");
```

Try above code and let me know, whether it works for you.

Comment: Oh my budha it works :D thankyou so much, i will need to dig deeper about this. Thankyou Mahipal !!!

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that you are not opening the login dropdown prior to attempting to find the login button. You will need to find the Dropdown element, click on it, then find the login fields and button and perform your actions.

Comment: i did, i found the element of the drop down. In the find by Elements, i clicked on it and attempted to find the login form. In the Action i hover the mouse over it then attempted to send keys.