# Unable To Click Element Inside Iframe - NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, selenium

I navigate to the website, switch to the correct iframe, and everything seems to work fine, but once I need to interact with an element it throws the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException
```

CODE:

```
# IMPORT
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep

# NAVIGATE
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Program Files (X86)\\Google\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('http://www.foxnews.com/politics/2018/01/17/ice-plans-major-sweep-in-san-francisco-area-report-says.html')

# SWITCH TO IFRAME
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//IFRAME[contains(@src, "https://spoxy-shard4.spot.im/v2/spot/")]')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//INPUT[@placeholder='Your nickname...']").click()
```

I've tried targeting other elements as well, but it always gives an error:

```
"no such element"
"element not found"
"is not clickable at point (485, 873). Other element would receive the click: <p class="alert-text">...</p>".
```

Comment: Add some wait before click event

Comment: tried, but it doesn't help

Comment: It seem to be hidden. Can you see that input field on page?

Comment: Try:   driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))

Comment: You might have to scroll to it first & then try switching to the iframe

Comment: @C. Gaboury - I can scrape the source and see the contents.. my code works to connect with the right iframe I just can't interact for some reason.

Comment: @Amit - thanks for the suggestion I'll give it a try

Comment: Explain in words what you are trying to do. I'm looking at the site and I can see the conversation area that are you trying to access in the IFRAME but I don't see the INPUT you are referencing. What specifically are you trying to do in that IFRAME?

Comment: I'm trying to click on the area to leave a comment. It should respond by creating a popup prompting login.

Comment: Are you sure is that the correct frame? And are you sure its not inside multiple frames?

Answer (score 1):

I visited a website and I found two problems, I am not 100% sure what you are trying to do so I am considering you are trying to click on comment input field.

**First Problem**
Sometimes this yellow banner appears at the bottom, which is on top of all the elements so if you will try to click on any element which is beneath this you will you will get the `ElementNotVisible` exception with message that someother element might receive the click.

**Solution**: Wait until banner appears and if it does close the banner

**Second Problem**
You are trying to click on the `input field` which is hidden so even if banner doesn't appear you will get the `ElementNotVisible` Exception.

**Solution**: Rather than clicking on the `input` element click on it's parent `div`

Here is the code which is working.

```
 def is_element_exist(identifier, timeout=30):
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)
    try:
        return wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(identifier))
    except TimeoutException:
        return None


def accept_alert(timeout=30):
    alert = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.alert_is_present())
    print alert.text
    driver.switch_to.alert.accept()


# NAVIGATE
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome("h:\\bin\\chromedriver.exe", )
driver.get('http://www.foxnews.com/politics/2018/01/17/ice-plans-major-sweep-in-san-francisco-area-report-says.html')

#Wait for yellow popup footer and close it
close_button = is_element_exist((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='close']"), 10)
if close_button:
    close_button.click()

# SWITCH TO IFRAME
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//IFRAME[contains(@src, "https://spoxy-shard4.spot.im/v2/spot/")]')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='sppre_editor']/div").click()

#Wait and accept the alert
accept_alert()
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to click on the correct element. I'm trying to click on the area to leave a comment. It should respond by creating a popup asking to login.

Comment: I get a "NoSuchElementException". I think it maybe due to some kind of javascript protection. Similar to this maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27927964/selenium-element-not-visible-exception

Comment: could be if your internet connection is slow. or if site is working slow. however above code works perfectly find on side. I am able to land to singup page for comment.