# Scraping hidden elements

Tags: python, html, selenium

My question is twofold:

1) I'm attempting to log on to this [page](https://www.findacode.com/signin.html), source is [here](https://pastebin.com/Cf0Z2uFx), using the code below. It's fine to use the credentials I've provided, which will expire 28 days from now but it's relatively painless to create a trial account for those viewing this content after that.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver_path = 'Path to my downloaded chromedriver.exe file'
url_login = 'https://www.findacode.com/signin.html'
username = 'jd@mailinator.com'
password = 'm%$)-Y95*^.1Gin+'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, chrome_options=options)

driver.get(url_login)
assert '_submit_check' in driver.page_source
driver.find_element_by_name('id').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Sign In']").submit()
```

I receive the following error for all 3 elements:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

My command of html/css/javscript isn't as strong but I've tried using waits per this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27927964/selenium-element-not-visible-exception) and received a timeout. Was going to try ActionChains from that thread next but love to hear from someone with more knowledge on this about how to proceed.

2) Ultimately I want to scrape specific code history data from this [url](https://www.findacode.com/code.php?set=CPT&c=0001U) (source [here](https://pastebin.com/a6x7rpBd)) by varying the code (last 5 characters of the url) in a loop. A user has to be logged in, hence my first question above, and the way to view the information I'm after in the browser is to expand the light purple "Code History" table. The specific information I'm after is the date from any row where the Action column is 'Added' and the Notes column is 'Code Added':

```
Date       Action Notes 
2018-01-01 Added  First appearance in code
2017-02-01 Added  Code Added
```

My question here is since the table, which I believe is hidden, needs to be expanded with a click to expose the data I'm after, how do I proceed?

**Edit**
Here's code, pseudo code and commentary to explain my 2nd question.

```
url_code = "https://www.findacode.com/code.php?set=CPT&c="
driver.get(url_code+'0001U') # i'm presuming that this will preserve the login session
driver.find_element_by_id('history').click() # i intend for this to expand the Code History section and expose the table shown earlier in the post but it's not doing that
check whether the phrase "Code Added" occurs in page source
if so, grab the date that is in the <td nowrap> tag that is 2 tags to the left
```

I can use BeautifulSoup for the last two lines if not possible with Selenium but I need help understanding why I'm not seeing the data I want to scrape

Answer (score 3):

There are two forms on page with inputs `@name="id"`, `@name="password"` and "Sign in" button. The first one is hidden. You need to handle form with `@name="login"`:

```
form = driver.find_element_by_name('login')
form.find_element_by_name('id').send_keys(username)
form.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(password)
form.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Sign In']").submit()
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Still coming up to speed on html. Any thoughts on the 2nd part of my question?

Comment: There is no code for second part, so issue is not quite clear... If you need to get several URLs changing the page number, you can define `counter = 1` and use `driver.get('https://www.findacode.com/code.php?set=CPT&c=000%sU' % counter)` in a loop + increment `counter` by `1` on each iteration

Comment: I'll try to add some code for that in a bit but my challenge there is more about how I can get to the contents of the table

Comment: So there is a third issue also? :) It'd be better to create tickets for each issue as it will be hard to analyze the code and search for root-cause

Comment: There isn't a 3rd issue, just a 2nd issue which apparently might not have been as clearly articulated. I'm just clarifying that the 2nd issue is more about getting to the data than looping through the codes.

Answer (score 1):

To login into this website you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *elements to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  driver_path = 'Path to my downloaded chromedriver.exe file'
  url_login = 'https://www.findacode.com/signin.html'
  username = 'jd@mailinator.com'
  password = 'm%$)-Y95*^.1Gin+'

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument('--headless')
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get(url_login)
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//form[@name='login']//input[@name='id']"))).send_keys(username)
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@name='login']//input[@name='password']").send_keys(password)
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@name='login']//input[contains(@value,'Sign In')]").submit()
  print("Logged In successfully")
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Logged In successfully
  ```

Comment: Can you explain why OP **need** *to induce WebDriverWait* while it works perfectly without WebDriverWait?

Comment: @Andersson he is asking in every one of his post to use webdriver wait, I still don't have any idea why he does so!