# Python Selenium click on input tag by data-filter-tag value

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to make selenium click on input checkbox but facing different errors. 
only difference between these checkbox's is data-filter-tag value so I tried this.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[data-filter-tag='am']").click()
```

ERROR

```
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable
```

web page is loaded 100%

HTML CODE :

```
                            <ul>

                            <li class="filter-checkbox active-filter">
                                <div class="custom-checkbox" style="background-position: 0px center;"><input name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$BaseContentPlaceHolder$pmainedge2edge4_0$ctl00$ctl14$rpFilters$ctl01$ctl00" type="checkbox" class="dealer-locator-filter" data-filter-tag="c"></div>
                                <span data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-trigger="hover" data-content="" data-original-title="" title="">


<i class="c-icon hq-icon hq-icon-crown-dealer hq-icon-small " title=""></i>Crown dealers
                                </span>
                            </li>

                            <li class="filter-checkbox active-filter">
                                <div class="custom-checkbox" style="background-position: 0px center;"><input name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$BaseContentPlaceHolder$pmainedge2edge4_0$ctl00$ctl14$rpFilters$ctl02$ctl00" type="checkbox" class="dealer-locator-filter" data-filter-tag="r"></div>
                                <span data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-trigger="hover" data-content="" data-original-title="" title="">


<i class="c-icon hq-icon hq-icon-reseller hq-icon-small " title=""></i>Authorized dealers
                                </span>
                            </li>

                            <li class="filter-checkbox active-filter">
                                <div class="custom-checkbox" style="background-position: 0px center;"><input name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$BaseContentPlaceHolder$pmainedge2edge4_0$ctl00$ctl14$rpFilters$ctl03$ctl00" type="checkbox" class="dealer-locator-filter" data-filter-tag="cs"></div>
                                <span data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-trigger="hover" data-content="" data-original-title="" title="">


<i class="c-icon hq-icon hq-icon-servicing-workshop hq-icon-small " title=""></i>Has service
                                </span>
                            </li>

                            <li class="filter-checkbox active-filter">
                                <div class="custom-checkbox" style="background-position: 0px center;"><input name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$BaseContentPlaceHolder$pmainedge2edge4_0$ctl00$ctl14$rpFilters$ctl04$ctl00" type="checkbox" class="dealer-locator-filter" data-filter-tag="am"></div>
                                <span data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-trigger="hover" data-content="" data-original-title="" title="">


<i class="c-icon hq-icon hq-icon-category-robotic-lawn-mowers hq-icon-small " title=""></i>Automower® dealers
                                </span>
                            </li>

                            </ul>

                </div>
```

Site : [link](https://www.husqvarna.com/us/)

Complete code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver/chromedriver')
### website url
driver.get('https://www.husqvarna.com/us/')
sleep(6)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[data-filter-tag='am']").click()
```

Comment: would be easier to help if you included your whole code rather than just the snippet.

Comment: Let me edit again for better understanding, I did not include whole code because the above code is just web driver path and site link.
Site link is already given in the end.

Comment: wow ya. I tried a few things and no go. I'll look more into it later. but I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27927964/selenium-element-not-visible-exception/27931726). So maybe give that a look. If you figure it out, post a solution. I'm curious on how this one works.

Comment: Thankyou so much for reviewing it. I hope you can solve it.
I will update the question once I solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select the surrounding div of a checkbox with this rather nasty CSS selector, you can at least click a checkbox without an exception.

```
checkbox = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#MainContentPlaceHolder_BaseContentPlaceHolder_pmainedge2edge4_0_ctl00_ctl14_dealerFilters > section:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(1)")
checkbox.click()
```

There is a lot of JavaScript interfering with webdriver automation. I did not find a better solution yet, but at least you know there is a way to interact with that checkbox.