# Creating selenium webdriver in python and using it in robotframework

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, selenium2library

So i am practically stacked.
If you call the selenium2library keyword Open Browser a webdriver object instance will be created and placed in the browsercache(if i understand the functionality correctly). To this point i know how to acquire the created webdriver within a python class or script and use this webdriver with python-selenium commands.
As Documented here
[Pass existing Webdriver object to custom Python library for Robot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703870/pass-existing-webdriver-object-to-custom-python-library-for-robot-framework)

So i want to ask.
We create,in a python script,a webdriver object with selenium.webdriver as documented here 
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started

Is it possible now to use this webdriver object in robotframework-selenium2library's keywords?
Also is it possible to use this webdriver with selenium-python scripts without passing it everytime as an argument?
And how you do this?