# Extend RobotFramework SeleniumLibary

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, selenium2library

I am trying to extend the **RobotFramework SeleniumLibray** to override **open_browser** method. The problem is, I am not even sure which class I should override.

**Library**

[https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/blob/master/src/SeleniumLibrary/**init**.py](https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/blob/master/src/SeleniumLibrary/__init__.py)

following code gives the error.

if I extend the BrowserManagementKeywords class, I am not sure what should I pass as **ctx** in **constructor argument**.

```
from SeleniumLibrary import SeleniumLibrary
import env


class DriverManager(SeleniumLibrary):

    def open_browser(self, url, alias=None, ff_profile_dir=None):

        browser = env.capabilities.get("browserName")
        remote_url = env.host
        desired_capabilities = env.capabilities

        return super(DriverManager, self).open_browser(url, browser, alias, remote_url, desired_capabilities, ff_profile_dir)


DriverManager().open_browser("https://google.com")
```

Error

> AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'open_browser'

Comment: Can you explain what it is that you're trying to achieve functionally? I.e. the motivation to choose to override the class as opposed to creating a new library and passing the SeleniumLibrary object to it?

Comment: I am trying to run tests on mobile(using appium) as well as on browser (using selenium). I was thinking to write a class which over rides AppiumLibary or SeleniumLibaray based on my config. and then over ride open_browser and open_application to read from config.

Comment: That does not motivate the design choice to extend the class. When using Robot Framework most of us use Robot Script to automate the browser. So, what it that requires a python solution?

Comment: it's hide the underlying complexity. I am trying to create a new library in Python which will handle driver creation.

Comment: Have you had a look at this post which describes creating a [custom library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703870/pass-existing-webdriver-object-to-custom-python-library-for-robot-framework) that uses an existing Selenium?Library instance.

Comment: Is this really your code, or is that first `def` supposed to be `def open_browser(...)`?

Comment: @BryanOakley thanks. I might have made mistake while copying code

Comment: Is this the solution to your problem, or just a copy-and-past to [so] error?

Comment: It's not the solution, i made error in pasting code