# How to use web driver method to launch browser inside Robot framework

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I don't want to use open browser built in keyword of seleniumLibrary . How can I use `Webdriver.Chrome()` to launch a browser? I'm using python here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23704655/6793637

Answer (score 0):

create a customlibrary.py file (like so: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8pD5-SP_0c&t=133s)

type the code in

use that libary

```
library customlibrary.py
```