# RED Robot Framework Editor - Unexpected error: NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/markusbernhardt/selenium2library/utils/WebDriverCache

Tags: eclipse-plugin, robotframework, selenium2library

Im using RED robot framework editor with Java. Though i have added the jar file that contains
'com/github/markusbernhardt/selenium2library/utils/WebDriverCache', it errors as "NoClassDefFoundError"

I use robotframework-selenium2library-java-1.4.0.8 for creating java library.

Below is the console command generated in RED editor.

```
Command: C:\jython2.7.0\bin\jython.exe -J-Dpython.path=C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages -J-cp .;C:\Java\JarsKCC\Misc.jar;C:\Java\JarsKCC\KCCUtils.jar;C:\Java\JarsKCC\GetElementList.jar;C:\jython2.7.0\selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar;C:\jython2.7.0\robotframework-selenium2library-java-1.4.0.8 -m robot.run -P C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\Selenium2Library --listener C:\Users\CON_RT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RobotTempDir2533122362618779828\TestRunnerAgent.py:56178:False -s KCC_Automation.TestSuites.TestSeparateWebdriverInstance C:\Java\Workspace\KCC_Automation
Suite Executor: Robot Framework 3.0.2 (Jython 2.7.0 on java1.8.0_121)
```

Error received while execution is,

```
[ ERROR ] Unexpected error: NoClassDefFoundError: 
com/github/markusbernhardt/selenium2library/utils/WebDriverCache
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
at robot.utils.importer$py.import_$32(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\utils\importer.py:274)
at robot.utils.importer$py.call_function(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\utils\importer.py)
at robot.utils.importer$py._import_class_or_module$5(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\utils\importer.py:77)
at robot.utils.importer$py.call_function(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\utils\importer.py)
at robot.utils.importer$py.import_class_or_module$4(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\utils\importer.py:74)
at robot.utils.importer$py.call_function(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\utils\importer.py)
at robot.model.visitor$py.visit_suite$2(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\model\visitor.py:88)
at robot.model.visitor$py.call_function(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\model\visitor.py)
at robot.model.testsuite$py.visit$19(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\model\testsuite.py:161)
at robot.model.testsuite$py.call_function(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\model\testsuite.py)
at robot.model.itemlist$py.visit$11(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\model\itemlist.py:75)
at robot.model.itemlist$py.call_function(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\model\itemlist.py)
at robot.model.visitor$py.visit_suite$2(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\model\visitor.py:88)
at robot.model.visitor$py.call_function(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\model\visitor.py)
at robot.model.testsuite$py.visit$19(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\model\testsuite.py:161)
at robot.model.testsuite$py.call_function(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\model\testsuite.py)
at robot.model.itemlist$py.visit$11(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\model\itemlist.py:75)
at robot.model.itemlist$py.call_function(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\model\itemlist.py)
at robot.model.visitor$py.visit_suite$2(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\model\visitor.py:88)
at robot.model.visitor$py.call_function(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\model\visitor.py)
at robot.model.testsuite$py.visit$19(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\model\testsuite.py:161)
at robot.model.testsuite$py.call_function(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\model\testsuite.py)
at robot.utils.application$py._execute$10(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\utils\application.py:94)
at robot.utils.application$py.call_function(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\utils\application.py)
at robot.utils.application$py.execute_cli$5(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\utils\application.py:49)
at robot.utils.application$py.call_function(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\robot\utils\application.py)
at runpy$py._run_code$9(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\runpy.py:73)
at runpy$py.call_function(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\runpy.py)
at runpy$py._run_module_as_main$14(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\runpy.py:161)
at runpy$py.call_function(C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\runpy.py)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
com.github.markusbernhardt.selenium2library.utils.WebDriverCache
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 190 more
```

Java code I used from this [blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220386/robotframework-selenium2library-and-external-libraries-pass-webdriver)

Note: I also verified with the dependency jar file 'robotframework-selenium2library-java-1.4.0.8-jar-with-dependencies'. I still face the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples in the 'blog' / stackoverflow post had some issues, with the key one being that the name of the class was changed since the answer was written on SO. However, when I compiled the jar file and added the jar file to the class path section of the `red.xml` none of the errors mentioned in the question were encountered. As the referred SO question had two approaches, I tried them both.

It appears to me that you have specified the directory and not the jar file for the `robotframework-selenium2library-java-1.4.0.8`.

```
C:\jython2.7.0\bin\jython.exe
-J-Dpython.path=C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages
-J-cp .
;C:\Java\JarsKCC\Misc.jar
;C:\Java\JarsKCC\KCCUtils.jar
;C:\Java\JarsKCC\GetElementList.jar
;C:\jython2.7.0\selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar
;C:\jython2.7.0\robotframework-selenium2library-java-1.4.0.8
-m robot.run
-P C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\Selenium2Library
--listener C:\Users\CON_RT~1\AppData\ ... \TestRunnerAgent.py:56178:False
-s KCC_Automation.TestSuites.TestSeparateWebdriverInstance 
C:\Java\Workspace\KCC_Automation
```

So my advice is to change this so that the classpath reflects the jar file: 
`;C:\jython2.7.0\robotframework-selenium2library-java-1.4.0.8\some-jar-name.jar`

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply. I just specified `C:\jython2.7.0\robotframework-selenium2library-java-1.4.0.8` and not given  `.jar` at the end under Classpath section in `Red.xml`. Hence the system considered as folder. I corrected it and executed successfully. As you said the code containing in 'blog' has created cast issues. That I need to work on.